# How to validate multiple same type input with same names in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I am a bit new to Javascript. I have a html form with multiple input types but with the same names occurring multiple types. I need to validate the form before inserting the data in the form into the database. I am able to update and insert into the database without JS validation but am unable to perform the validation part using javascript because of complications with handling inputs with the same names. 
Here is the form:

```
    <form name="confirmation" method="post" action="appointment.php" onsubmit="return check()">

        <label>Restaurant Name: </label>
        <input name="r_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[0]?>"><br>
        <label>Appointment Date: </label>
        <input name="app_date[]" type="date" value="<?php echo $row[1]?>"><br>
        Confirm:<select name="confirm[]"> 
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select><br><br>

    </form>
```

Here is the php code to update the database:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $names= $_POST['r_name'];
    $dates=$_POST['app_date'];
    $confirm=$_POST['confirm'];
    //echo $count;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    //echo "success";
        $value=$confirm[$i];
        if($value=="yes")
            $value="y";
        else 
            $value="n";
      //  echo $value;
        $result= mysql_query("update appointment set confirm='".$value."' where rname='".$names[$i]."';");
    }                       
}?>
```

To insert/update the data with same names in the form into the database I had to associate [] to their respective names for it was the easy way out. But I am having problem assessing it in javascript for the validation part. Could anyone suggest me how to go about doing it with a small code snippet with any of the names used for the input types used in the above form. Thanks.

Comment: Is this all the HTML there is?  I don't see multiple input elements with the same `name`.

Comment: It is OK to give the same "name" to several elements, but it is not OK to give them the same "id" value.

Comment: @Steve I am dynamically generating them(the html block above) so you are not seeing the input elements with same name.

Comment: @Pointy good that you pointed it out. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `name`s are the same for multiple input elements, you can use unique `id`s on the element if you want to target a specific element or you can use `class`es to target a group of similar elements.

```
<form>
    <input name="myInput[]" id="myInput_0" class="myInput" type="text" value="">
    <input name="myInput[]" id="myInput_1" class="myInput" type="text" value="">
    <input name="myInput[]" id="myInput_2" class="myInput" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Now you can target `myInput[0]` as `getElementById('myInput_0')` or all `myInput[]`s as `getElementByClassName('myInput')`

Comment: since i am dynamically generating the form size depending on the data from the server side using php, it would be an unwise option to use id tag as we wont know exactly the number of items with same names will be generated for performing client side form validation. Hence I do feel this would be a bad choice.

Comment: Well, then you are left with the `class` approach and looping over the node array you get back from `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementsByName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery library http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

You can use this validation after de excute the submit post and the librery make all the validations.